# Error running Object Detection API on Google ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am having a problem getting a job to run on Google ML for retraining of an Object Detection API SSD Mobilenet using my own training data.   Note I can train succesfully on my local machine.   Here are the details.   I have tried different versions of tensorflow for the gcloud (and corresponding cloud.yaml) files and all have failed.  I am running locally version 1.8 of tensorflow with Object Detection API (+slim).

NOTE:  Attempting to retrain the SSD_Mobile net model that I copied to my Google CLoud store and originally located at object_detection\ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17\model.ckpt

TensorFlow version (use command below):
have tried numerous version including 1.8 (not Google ML support 1.8 and this is the version used locally to make the TFRecord training files)

NOTE: trying to run training example (That trains locally ) on Google ML. Execute job request using gcloud tool. Followed instructions at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md.
COMMAND executed from tensorflow/models/research

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training grewe_object_detection_6 --runtime-version 1.8 --job-dir=gs://BLAHBLAH-storage/Train --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz --module-name object_detection.train --region us-central1 --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml -- --
```

**Describe the problem**
See error below. Have tried to alter the version of tensorflow used (note locally when run successfully using 1.8 so believe as that is what used to package TFRecord it should work on Google ML) --so tried to update the provided cloud.yaml (tried for version 1.2, 1.4, 1.6 and 1.8 and also tried updating the setup.py in models/research and nothing works.

I tried last the following for my cloud.yaml file

```
trainingInput: runtimeVersion: "1.8" scaleTier: CUSTOM masterType: standard_gpu workerCount: 5 workerType: standard_gpu parameterServerCount: 3 parameterServerType: standard
```

I tried last the following for my setup.py

**_`"""Setup script for object_detection."""

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Pillow>=1.0', 'Matplotlib>=2.1', 'Cython>=0.28.1']

setup(
name='object_detection',
version='0.1',
install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
include_package_data=True,
packages=[p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('object_detection')],
description='Tensorflow Object Detection Library',
)`_**
```

This is the error from log on Google Cloud ML console
ERROR message:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__ return self.gen.next() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 1000, in managed_session self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session start_standard_services=start_standard_services) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 726, in prepare_or_wait_for_session init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 279, in prepare_session config=config) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 207, in _restore_checkpoint saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1802, in restore {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path}) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run run_metadata_ptr) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) UnavailableError: OS Error The replica worker 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session start_standard_services=start_standard_services) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 734, in prepare_or_wait_for_session max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 406, in wait_for_session sess) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 490, in _try_run_local_init_op sess.run(self._local_init_op) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run run_metadata_ptr) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) UnavailableError: OS Error [[Node: init_ops/init_all_tables_S2 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:master/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=6383848822399600260, tensor_name="edge_29_init_ops/init_all_tables", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:master/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]] The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 747, in train master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__ return self.gen.next() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 1000, in managed_session self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session start_standard_services=start_standard_services) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 734, in prepare_or_wait_for_session max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 406, in wait_for_session sess) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 490, in _try_run_local_init_op sess.run(self._local_init_op) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run run_metadata_ptr) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) UnavailableError: OS Error The replica worker 2 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 747, in train master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__ return self.gen.next() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 1000, in managed_session self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session start_standard_services=start_standard_services) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 734, in prepare_or_wait_for_session max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 406, in wait_for_session sess) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 490, in _try_run_local_init_op sess.run(self._local_init_op) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run run_metadata_ptr) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) UnavailableError: OS Error The replica worker 4 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 747, in train master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__ return self.gen.next() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 1000, in managed_session self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session start_standard_services=start_standard_services) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 734, in prepare_or_wait_for_session max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 406, in wait_for_session sess) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 490, in _try_run_local_init_op sess.run(self._local_init_op) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run run_metadata_ptr) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) UnavailableError: OS Error To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=36123659232&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fgrewe_object_detection_8&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%22grewe_object_detection_8%22
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved by using --runtime-version flag 1.2 as @iwz1992 mentioned and having Tensorflow and Jupyter in the setup.py

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue. The object detection team is working on a new binary to fix it. At the mean time, you can use runtime version 1.2 on Cloud ML Engine which should work.

Comment: The version 1.2 gives errors also.    A question - do I have to actually download on my computer a different version of 1.8  or it is sufficient to simply request 1.2 in gcloud and cloud.yaml files?    I am making the TFRecord using tools from tensorflow 1.8 on my local machine?  Also, I am using the ssd_mobilenet model checkpoint that comes with the latest object detection api --will this work.

Comment: This is the error I get when trying 1.2 (when I have locally 1.8 installed)he replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_modunal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 164, in build functools.partial(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, buffer_size=8 * 1000 * 1000), AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data' The replica worker 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1.

Comment: The error means that tf.data is not supported in tf 1.2. It seems that it's still under tf.contrib(https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data) at that time. And it's totally fine to install TF 1.8 on your local environment and submit training job using runtime 1.2 on CloudML Engine.